# How to keep the updated rows for a period of time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I am working with small project using SQL Server, and I need some help from you, to clarify the problems I am having with a task.

What I am trying to do is update the row in table and keep these updated rows for a period of time.

For example I am using this code to update:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[updtprice]
    @bc int,
    @price float
AS
    UPDATE tblproduct 
    SET Price = @price
    WHERE Barcode =  @bc
```

What I am trying to do is, for example I update the price of the product with barcode 2233 from 0.99 cent to 0.70 (today). And I want the price to be reverted to old one after one or two week( certain data set by user).

How can I accomplish this task?

Thanks to everyone

Comment: Wait two weeks and run another query to change it back.

Comment: You want history and  a TVF with a parameter, kind of number of days, hours ... , a lag to apply to history table. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables

Comment: In your prices table, have an expiration date column. Run a job every night which deletes expired prices (I.e. sets the "delete flag".)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn it should run automatically, because the person who will use the system, maybe will forget to run query back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be other ways to do it but it sounds like you need another table that records the previous value and date that it expires. Then you would have a "job" that runs daily that takes note of any expired and does the update back to previous value.

OR you have additional columns in this table with the special price and expiration date and any applications that use that row look at the special price, is it still good, if so use it, if not use the regular price.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, the only way to properly do this is either:

1. Write a script that does this.
2. Write a scheduled task in MS SQL.

Both not great ways to do it in all honesty. I would personally go with option 1 if it's a web-application and option 2 if it's just a Database.

Answer (score 0):

you can have 3 columns in your table.

- actual_price
- current_price
- price_update_date

**actual_price** columns will always have exact price of the product.
you can update the **current_price** with the **discounted price** and also update the **strong text** price_update_date column when updating the **current_price**.

like.

```
  ALTER procedure [dbo].[updtprice]
  @bc int,
  @price float

  as

  update tblproduct set current_price= @price,
  price_update_date=SYSDATETIME()
  where
  Barcode =  @bc
```

and then you can create another stored Proc which will run everyday at 12 am.
and chech if **current_time -price_update_date** is greater than or equal to your **threshold** then update the **current_price** of the product with **actual_price**